# Conform project imported file doesn't reflex in Devops server Migrator validate report

Tags: azure-devops-server-2020

I am working to migrate Azure Devops server 2020 to Azure Devops services and following this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/migrate/migration-processtemplates?view=azure-devops) to resolve errors.

Based on the error finding in the Migrator validate report, we used "Conform project" powershell script to fix the process template and imported the process file back to server. We found that the correct file was imported and we did a project export(ExportProjectTemplate.ps1) to validate the files were imported.

However, when we run the Migrator validate again in the server. The error is still exist in the report and the pre-modified "ProcessConfiguration.xml" found in the zip file used for project validation.

Should I use witadmin deletefield to delete "PortfolioBacklog" element or other steps I can follow to fix this issue?

```
Error message in the Migration validator report
[Error  @18:17:51.083] Step : ProcessValidation - Failure Type - Validation failed : Invalid process template: WorkItem Tracking\TypeDefinitions\Feature.xml:: TF402547: Element PortfolioBacklog requires that for work item type Feature you map at least one state to metastate Complete.

[Error  @18:17:51.084] Step : ProcessValidation - Failure Type - Validation failed : Invalid process template: WorkItem Tracking\Process\ProcessConfiguration.xml:: The following element contains an error: PortfolioBacklog(Microsoft.FeatureCategory)/Columns. TF400529: This element defines the columns that appear on the backlog. You must set all values to fields that exist in at least one of the work item types belonging to the category. The following fields do not exist in any of the work item types: Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ValueArea.

[Error  @18:17:51.085] Step : ProcessValidation - Failure Type - Validation failed : Invalid process template: WorkItem Tracking\Process\ProcessConfiguration.xml:: The following element contains an error: PortfolioBacklog(Microsoft.FeatureCategory)/States'. The following state does not exist in any of the work item types: Active, Resolved, Closed.
```

Should I use witadmin deletefield to delete "PortfolioBacklog" element or other steps I can follow to fix this issue?